# Batch file: set variables using a dynamic number of tokens

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am reading through a file using a batch script. Basically I want to read a specific line and set its tokens to different variables. The problem is, the line does not have a fixed number of tokens. Consider the following file format:

```
Line 1 Domains www.google.com www.yahoo.com www.reddit.com ...
Line 2 541 5435 322 123
Line 3 273 123 432 123
```

My script will be reading the line whose third token equals "Domains" and store the tokens that follow into different variables. In this case, I would set `Domain1=www.google.com`, `Domain2=www.yahoo.com`, `Domain3=www.reddit.com`, and so on. My code will look something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=3*" %%A in (%file%) do (
    if ("%%A"=="Domains") (
        REM Delimit %%B with a space and store each token into different variables
    )
)
```

**EDIT: Problem solved. It is too soon for me to answer my own question due to insufficient rep, but here is my solution starting from Jeremy's post:**

```
set index=1
for /f "tokens=3*" %%A in (%file%) do (
    if ("%%A"=="Domains") (
        for %%C in (%%B) do (
            set Domain!index!=%%C
            set /A index+=1
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't solve your problem exactly the way you wanted it solved but I think this is a workable solution:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=3*" %%A in (%file%) do (
  if "%%A"=="Domains" (
    set domains=%%B
  )
)

for %%A in (%domains%) do (
  echo %%A
)
```

Comment: This is more than half of the solution that I've eventually come to and it helped a lot! Basically I made a nested for loop (i.e. I put your second loop into the first one) and replaced `%domains%` with `%%B`.